# What is the difference between these 2 ways of opening connection?

Tags: php, mysqli

We see in many places these two types of code for creating database connection in PHP with Mysqli, so what is the technical difference between them?

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$db_name);
```

And

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password);
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($conn,$db_name);
```

Comment: Looks like you used another variable and another method to connect to the DB with the help of connection variable, but it really helps to handle multiple databases, something like this `mysqli_select_db($conn,"test")`, i think only difference is based on usage of it.

Answer (score 0):

There is none. They are the same. There is also a third, better way which you have not listed here.

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$conn = new \mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);
$conn->set_charset('utf8mb4');
```

OOP style is easier to read and less prone to errors. Additionally you should always enable exception mode and specify the correct connection charset. This is the best way.

From the PHP manual for `mysqli_select_db`:

> **Note:**
>
> This function should only be used to change the default database for the connection. You can select the default database with 4th parameter in mysqli_connect().

Comment: but in first mysqli_connect() it takes 4 arguments and in second mysqli_connect() it takes 3 arguments.

Comment: All arguments are optional. The 4th argument is the DB name, which you can pass in directly to the `mysqli_connect` or you can select the DB on the next line with `mysqli_select_db` The end result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a database name upon connection is just a convenient short-cut since most of the times you want to start using some specific database immediately.

Perhaps you're confused because you assume that a database connection is restricted to a single database; it isn't. `$db_name` is merely the *selected* database. If you have the appropriate privileges you can either use objects from a different database (by specifying the database name as prefix) or switch the selected database as many times as you want (for which you'd use `mysqli_select_db()`); the plain SQL equivalents would be:

```
USE shop;
SELECT *
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN crm.customers c ON o.customer_id = c.customer_id;
```

```
USE crm;
SELECT *
FROM customers;
```